# How to import my R codes in TeXnicCenter

Tags: listings, miktex, installing

This package is basically writting `R` codes in LaTeX but I am typing codes in TeXnicCenter when I use this command it doesn't work to copy codes from R. Please tell me how I can write my `R` codes in TeXnicCenter?
I'm using this code:

```
 \documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle} 
 \usepackage{listing}
 \begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
fib <- function(n) {
  if (n < 2)
    n
  else
    fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
}
fib(10) # => 55enter code here
\end{lstlisting}
```

I would want to write this code in TeXnicCenter:

```
 okfd <- function(coord, data, argvals=seq(0, 1, len = dim(data)[1]), 
                 argnames=c("argument", "sites", "values"),
                 new.coord=NULL,                
                 nbasis=max(50,dim(data)[1]), lambda = 0,
                 max.dist.variogram=NULL,nugget.fix=NULL){
```

Answer (score 1):

This requires the `listings` package.
Your code works like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
enter code h`okfd <- function(coord, data,
 argvals=seq(0, 1, len = dim(data)[1]), 
argnames=c("argument", "sites", "values"),
new.coord=NULL,                
nbasis=max(50,dim(data)[1]), lambda = 0,
max.dist.variogram=NULL,nugget.fix=NULL){
\end{lstlisting} 

\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image: second listing]

## In case you don't have the listings package

If you don't have the `listings` package, you have to install it. For MiKTeX,   you go to the start menu > MiKTeX > MiKTeX Console (you might have to start it as an administrator) and then go to the options. It has an option called "Always install missing packages on-the-fly". Select this option and close the window.

Comment: \documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

Comment: will  ur given command work in texniccenter sir?? im using \documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle} in texniccenter

Comment: not working in texnicenter ,.
even just i installed textstudio to check ur code it gives an error File `listings.sty' not found. \usepackage ,
when i install this package listing.sty still same error

Comment: im using MiktTeX ,....plz tell me how to install this listing  ??

Comment: yes at the end u given  , im trying to get this , will tell u , it works r not ,,,thnks sooo much

Comment: it is working sirrrrrr , thnkuuuuuuu

Comment: i accept and voted